# Put on a final notice in one day by new manager

Tags: management

Okay so I was rehired at my old job and they have an extensive training program. I had to go through the training again even though I had been rehired. I was constantly finished with the courses quickly and bored so I was frequently caught on my phone which I received a verbal warning for excessive phone usage under the issue of conduct.

The training program had different levels with different instructors. I had only been with this instructor one week and our first one on one encounter was her issuing me a write up. To issue the write up she called my manager that I would be assigned to after training into the meeting as well after I had been assigned to his team literally that day. During the meeting she has no formal write up to issue me she just told me “I’m putting you on a verbal warning” and summed up the reason as excessive cell phone use.

While in the meeting she tells me that while she has me there she would like to discuss my attendance. Just some background information I had two emergencies prior to being under her instruction, one being impacted wisdom teeth and a small family emergency. I’ll like to note that I came to work the next day after having my wisdom teeth pulled as well as offered to come back to work when I had the family emergency which I was told “it wouldn’t be worth is” I say this to point out I did my best to be there every day of training.

I had already been spoken to previously about my attendance by the manager that was instructing me at the time and the conversation was noted in my file. So when she brought up the issue of attendance I expressed to her how I feel the conversation was unfair and that I had not since missed any work and have already been spoken to. She told me “I will have this conversation with you everyday if I want to” which baffles me as to why a manger would want to speak about something that is not happening.

So after she expressed that I felt defeated in the conversation and just completely shut down and stopped talking besides acknowledging that I understand. Three hours later I’m being called into another meeting to let me know I’m being put on a final notice for not being receptive to feedback and for trying to change the subject when she was talking. Also she told me it has been observed that two hours after she wrote me up I was observed throwing a fit by slamming objects on my desk. When I ask who observed or what the actual action was she says she’s not willing to share. Other people in my training class also felt she was extremely rude and unfair. The instructor went on maternity leave a week after this incident and luckily I was not fired as others have said they believe they would’ve been fired as well if she continued to instruct us.

Due to this final notice I have not received my yearly merit and not company bonus which is 15% of my salary. I’m extremely upset because I do not feel being put on a final warning was warranted. I am a very good employee and have never had any issues with conduct EVER. Every previous manager that heard this news about me was baffled as well as they know how well I do my job and have never had any issues with me either. I want to know what you would do in my shoes to present a case as to why it was not warranted. I am meeting with an ER rep and a VP to over turn the final notice I just want to ensure I build a strong case.

Comment: Welcome! This is a big wall of text. Can you try to shorten it, or put in a timeline ("A happened; the next day B occurred")? How long has it been since you completed training?

Comment: I got put on a verbal prior to lunch ... went to lunch ... went to a training meeting ... then back to my desk ... this is when the alledge “fit” that nobody else heard and she won’t disclose who saw or what was observed ... then I get called in for a final notice .. I was written up in May and it was over and completed in August but my company isn’t giving anyone a raise or merit if at any point you were on a final notice

Comment: @Janetodadoe Welcome! An interesting post, but difficult to read and to be honest it's not entirely clear what you are asking. Please edit your question, perhaps add a summary of your comment at the bottom.

Comment: @Janetodadoe Please do not deface your question because you want to delete it - we consider that vandalism here. Questions with a positive answer cannot be deleted by the OP. If you wish to have this question removed or disassociated from your account, you can flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: I'm sorry this happened to you, it sounds unfair. When you say "what you would do in my shoes to present a case" **I'm not sure how to answer** because I don't know what country you are in or what type of case you are bringing. E.g. is this one that the law allows? Is it a formal appeals process within your company? Have you just asked for a meeting and they granted it?

Answer (score 10):

You ask what should you do to argue that you deserve your merit raise despite having been written up in a way you believe was unfair.

I think you are risking your merit raise for the coming year, and possibly your employment, by bringing this up and you should drop the matter.*

By your own account, you were being rude,

> I was constantly finished with the courses quickly and bored so I was frequently caught on my phone which I received a verbal warning for excessive phone usage under the issue of conduct.

You later said you completely shut down during a discussion about your behavior and attendence. Despite the fact that you feel some of that feedback was unwarranted, the additional disciplinary action against you for "not being open to feedback" sounds warranted as well.

The fact that some of your colleagues are privately consolatory towards you is not evidence that they actually agree with you, but more likely that they don't feel comfortable debating the matter with you. Either they don't have time, or they find it more socially acceptable to be in agreement rather than raise an argument.

The issue of the incident at your desk might be a complete fabrication intended to get you fired. Or it might be a miscommunication or a misinterpretation of events. In any case, proving something didn't happen, especially when evidence is being withheld is extremely difficult and more than likely, if someone is willing to lie to get rid of you, and they're being protected by management as you've described, you're going to get fired.

I'm sure it's frustrating, but the best course of action is to accept the situation and either improve your standing at the office or find another place to work.

(* Unless you have a very good reason to believe this situation arose due to some sort of misconduct that was illegal on the part of your employer, and you can prove it in a court of law, and a reputable lawyer has advised you that doing so is a good idea.)

Comment: the OP is trying to delete this non-question.  Glen, there's a ridiculous problem on SO where one cannot delete a question, if it has an answer.  I'd actually suggest you just delete your answer so the OP can delete the (utterly pointless) question (which the OP apparently wants to delete for privacy or whatever reasons).  This is actually a quandry on SO.